# Filter File Content Golang

Tags: for-loop, filter, utf-8, rune

Here  is a file which contains the various data types in random sequence, separated by a space (multilingual strings, all types int and float, Boolean types), how to filter him and display each data type separately (for example, first strings, then real numbers  , then integers, then booleans) without importing additional packages and using only a UTF-8 table, for loop and built-in data types?

Example

INPUT: 2091.63037 "авторизация успешна" 08 "temps de visite" 10.218 true

OUTPUT: "авторизация успешна" "temps de visite" 2091.63037 10.218 08 true